# Equivalent of ctrl c in command to cancel a program

Tags: linux, command-line, copy-paste

I am running a long linux program in a remote machine, and I want to stop it, but my problem is that if I use the kill command then the program will exit without saving results. Normally what I do to finish the program is use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and in that case the program saves the results, but right now I am not in the machine that is running the session so I cannot press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

My question is: is there any way to do in a remote way the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Try:

```
kill -SIGINT processPIDHere
```

Basically <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd> sends the `SIGINT` (interrupt) signal while kill sends the `SIGTERM` (termination) signal by default unless you specify the signal to send.

Comment: How do I find out the processPID? I am using a web shell to test ping on my router and then I cannot kill the process...

Comment: @AeroWang you can run a process search for `ping` like this: `ps aux | grep "ping"`, the first number in the column is the pid.

Comment: sadly the ping stdout info would overwhelm the human input. @adrianTNT

Comment: This also works in OSX. Just use signal code instead of a name because in OSX it's INT. `kill -2 PID`

Answer (score 8):

ctrl c just sends a SIGINT signal, but there is some other signals that is a little more soft. http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Termination-Signals.html

I think that you can use the the kill command to send some other signal.
(see man kill for more info)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example for mongod

To start the daemon from the command line:

```
mongod &
```

Then later

```
kill -SIGINT `pgrep mongod`
```

Answer (score 5):

If you control the long-running remote process, you could install a signal handler for SIGTERM (see `man signal` and `man sigaction` and the many SO questions on this topic), to cleanup nicely before dieing.

That is a very common thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind as well in your signal handler, that it is like an interrupt handler in that you are *very* limited as to what you are allowed to do in it without corrupting the rest of your program. The best thing you can do here is set an atomic_t "should_quit" variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing as below way

```
killall -2 <ProgramName>
```

or

```
kill -2 <PID of your process>
```

I used to forget the the name of signal. i.e SIGINT/SIGKILL here so i am using number for that like killall -2 or killall -9